# How to draw the root locus of the open loop transfer function $s e^{as}$

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory, linear-control

How to draw the root locus of the following open loop transfer function with respect to $a$
\begin{equation}
G(s) = s e^{as}
\end{equation}
where $a \ge 0$ and $a$ is the variable.

Comment: This is $\{W_k(-1/a) \}$ where $W_k$ is the $k$-branch of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: @user1952009 thank you. can you be more specific?

Comment: We want to solve $z e^z = -a$. Let $C = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} - x e^x$. If $a \in (0, C]$ then it has one negative solution and infinitely many complex solutions. If $a > C$ then it has only complex solutions which accumulate at $\pm i \infty$

Comment: @user1952009 Why we want to solve $z e^e = -a$ and what is $z$?

Comment: @user1952009 Could you edit your comment as a complete answer so that it is more clear and understandable? thank you.

Comment: No. Did you try reading the [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) ?

Comment: Your question is not totally clear. One draws the root locus diagram of a transfer function, not of an equation. The gain in the diagram is multiplicative, not any variable in the transfer function. Evan's usual rules for drawing the root locus apply to systems in the pole-zero form; they are not directly useful for delay systems. A common technique is to use approximations, such as Padé approximants, for the exponential.

Comment: @Pait Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @user1952009 I think you have misunderstood my question because I did not explain it very clearly. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I did understand you want to know where are the zeros of $G(s) = s e^{as}+1$

Comment: @user1952009 Then the answer should be $W(-a)/a$. right?

Comment: @user1952009 Do you mean $F(s) = a(G(\frac{s}{a})+1)=se^s + a$ whose zeros are at $W(-a$?

Comment: I meant $F(s) = a G(s/a) = s e^s+a$ so yes the zeros are a $W(-a)/a$.

Answer (score 0):

I think your $a$ should be negative because only then you will have a positive input output delay. If $a$ is positive this would imply that your output is faster than your input.

If you are using MATLAB you could try to plot approximations to the solutions by using the Padé approximation.

```
s = tf('s');
G = s*exp(-s);
G_pade = pade(G,3); % 3rd order pade approximation
rlocus(G_pade);
```

In general, you should not use the root locus method for transfer functions with delays. As you can see the approximations lead to very complicated plots (check by using higher order Padé approximations), which comes from the fact that you need to use the Lambert function in the complex domain. You should rather use the Nyquist plot, which can handle delays.